# SQL adding values to a new column in an existing table?

Tags: sql

for example i created 
an employees table with columns named emp_id,emp_name,emp_job etc. and i wanted to add a manager number column ie. 'mgr_no', so i made this column with the alter statement with default null values.

Now my question is i already have 50 entries in the table and i want to enter 50 entries for mgr_no column which at the moment is empty or null,do i have to use the update command 50 times to fill the column, or is there a way to add values without running the update command 50 times.

*P.S:* iam using oracle 11g as it is bounded by my teacher.

Comment: You want ANOTHER table to store multiple values, with one value per row.

Comment: (Hm it sounds to me like they just want to update several rows at once.)

Comment: cant i store multiple values in the mgr_no column in the same table employee?

Comment: The `UPDATE` statement by default updates _all_ rows that match the filter. So just writing `UPDATE employees SET mgr_no = 123` will set _all 50 of your employees_ to have manager 123. You actually have to use a `WHERE` to _limit_ this behavior. If you want to set the manager to 123 only for employees with job `accounting`, you'd use `UPDATE employees SET mgr_no = 123 WHERE emp_job = 'accounting'`

Comment: @CherryDT yes, is it not possible

Comment: If you need to set several rows to the _same_ new value, you can just do what I described above, use a broader filter (or no filter at all) in the `UPDATE`. But if you want to set them all to different values, then yes you have to do 50 updates, that's pretty normal.

Comment: @CherryDT so i have to set the boundries

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of the question, I'll make an answer out of my comments

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want to update all (or many) rows to have the *same* new `mgr_no` value, or to 50 different values.

If you need 50 different values, then yes, you have to run 50 `UPDATE`s. That's pretty normal though and not a problem.

Otherwise, if you can "group" the new values: The `UPDATE` statement by default already updates *all* rows that match the filter. So just writing `UPDATE employees SET mgr_no = 123` will set *all 50 of your employees* to have manager 123. You actually have to use a `WHERE` to *limit* this behavior. If you want to set the manager to 123 only for employees with job `accounting`, you'd use `UPDATE employees SET mgr_no = 123 WHERE emp_job = 'accounting'`.